# A question about Orthogonal Decomposition Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

In a textbook that I'm reading the "Orthogonal Decomposition Theorem" is given as below:

[image]

However, there is no proof for equation (2). Can anyone prove it?
Thanks

Comment: Notice that $\frac{y\dot u_i}{u_i\dot u_i}u_i$ is the projection of $y$ on $u_i.$ So $\hat{y}$ is the projection of $y$ in $W.$ Imagine a plane $W$ and a vector $y$ and draw the shadow of $y$ on the plane $W.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\{u_1,\ldots ,u_p\}$ form a basis of $W$, each $\hat y$ can be written as

$$\hat y = c_1u_1 + \cdots + c_pu_p$$

Applying $u_i$ via dot product and using orthogonality gives:

$$\hat y \cdot u_i = c_i u_i\cdot u_i,\; i=1,\ldots , p$$

Hence,
$$c_i = \frac{\hat y \cdot u_i}{u_i\cdot u_i} = \frac{(\hat y+z) \cdot u_i}{u_i\cdot u_i} = \frac{y \cdot u_i}{u_i\cdot u_i},$$

since $y= \hat y + z$ with $z\in W^{\perp}$.

Comment: how can you replace $\hat{y}$ with $(\hat{y}+z)$ in the last step?

Comment: Because $z$ is orthogonal to $W$.

Comment: I later noticed that the fact that $z$ is orthogonal to $W$ is proved later assuming (2), so it cannot be used to prove (2).

Comment: The word "assuming" might be a bit misleading here. For any $y$ we can define $\hat y = \frac{y\cdot u_1}{u_1\cdot u_1}+ \cdots +\frac{y\cdot u_p}{u_p\cdot u_p}$. Then, you can easily show that $z=y-\hat y$ is orthogonal to $W$. Just evaluate $z\cdot u_i$ for $i=1,\ldots , p$.

So, the calculation i gave shows why the coefficients $c_i$ in $\hat y$ have this specific look.